# Echoing Xpath w/ Dom

Tags: php, dom, xpath, curl

I know some similair questions have been asked, but I'm kind stuck here. I can't find any good tutorials to help me with this. But what I want to do should be very basic. Lets say I want to  grab the H1 "Top Questions" on Stackoverflow.com, using Chrome to get the Xpath I get this:

`//*[@id="h-top-questions"]`

So my question is; how do I now echo this? Using code snippets from all over the net I got this:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if (!$html) {
    die("something's wrong!");
}

//var_dump(strlen($data));

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$headerh1 = $xpath->query('//*[@id="h-top-questions"]');

foreach($headerh1 as $match) {
    print_r($match);    
}
?>
```

I assumed this would just output `<h1 id="h-top-questions">Top Questions</h1>`. But instead I get 
`DOMElement Object
(
)`
.

Could anyone help me out? I'm trying to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a DOMNodeList element by the result of the query method. [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)
Try to access the nodes through the item($index) method.

Comment: I think I got it, I changed `print_r($match);` to `echo $match->nodeValue . "\n";`. And now it works, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is you iterating through the nodes to get the  DOMNode instead of the item($index) method but it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the content of an object in this manner, you would need to convert it to a string. If you wanted to do this, you could either simply `echo`/`print` it, or cast it to a string like this:

```
$string = (string) $object;
```

When an object is converted to a string, PHP calls it's `__toString()` method. Unfortunately a DOMElement object does not define one, so when you try and convert it to a string you will get the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in...

In this specific scenario, there is a poor man's work around that allows one to do this in a small amount code, and that is to bounce it through [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) using the [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) function - since the `SimpleXMLElement` class does define an `asXML()` method which will convert it back to an XML string. So you can do this:

```
foreach($headerh1 as $match) {
  $xml = simplexml_import_dom($match);
  echo $xml->asXML();
}
```

However, in this specific instance, this results in the following output:

```
<h1 id="h-top-questions">&#13;
        Top Questions    &#13;
     </h1>
```

So you see, there are some extra HTML entities leaking in there that were not in the original source code. This has happened somewhere between DOM and SimpleXML.

In order to get around this, it would be possible to:

- Pass the output through [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). This is not a great option as it may result in invalid XML/HTML output.
- Roll your own function to convert a DOMElement to a string. This is also not a great option as it would be very complex, and you would potentially need to recurse through many levels to successfully retrieve a full node list.

However, one thing to keep in mind here is that what you are doing does not have much of a practical application for anything other than testing and debugging. One would never really want to output a partial document.